# Single UITableView with different custom UITableViewCells issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, reloaddata

I have added UITableView into UIScrollView, I have created an IBOutlet for height constraint of UITableView which helps me in setting the content size of UITableview.

**I have 3 tabs and I switch tabs to reload data with different data source . Also the i have different custom cells when the tab changes.
So when the tab changes I call reloadData**

here is my cellForRow function

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Configure the cell...

        var cell:UITableViewCell!

        let event:Event!


        if(tableView == self.dataTableView)
        { 

                let eventCell:EventTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventTableViewCell

                eventCell.delegate = self


                    event = sectionsArray[indexPath.section].EventItems[indexPath.row]




                eventCell.eventTitleLabel?.text = "\(event.title)"
                eventCell.eventImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "def.png")


                if let img = imageCache[event.imgUrl] {
                    eventCell.eventImageView?.image = img
                }
                else {
                    print("calling image of \(indexPath.row)  \(event.imgUrl)")
                    //      let escapedString = event.imgUrl.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
                    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
                    do {
                        let encodedImageUrl = CommonEHUtils.urlEncodeString(event.imgUrl)
                        let urlObj = NSURL(string:encodedImageUrl)
                        if urlObj != nil {
                            let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(urlObj!, completionHandler: { ( data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                                guard let realResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where
                                    realResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                                        print("Not a 200 response, url = " + event.imgUrl)
                                        return
                                }
                                if error == nil {
                                    // Convert the downloaded data in to a UIImage object
                                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)


                                    // Store the image in to our cache
                                    self.imageCache[event.imgUrl] = image
                                    // Update the cell
                                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                        if let cellToUpdate:EventTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? EventTableViewCell  {
                                            cellToUpdate.eventImageView?.image = image
                                        }
                                    })
                                }
                            })
                            task.resume()
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print("Cant fetch image \(event.imgUrl)")
                    }
                }


                cell = eventCell
            }
            else if(secodTabClicked)
            {
                let Cell2:cell2TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier1, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cell2TableViewCell

               //Image loading again takes place here                

                cell = Cell2

            }
else if(thirdTabClicked)
            {
                let Cell3:cell3TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier2, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cell3TableViewCell

               //Image loading again takes place here                

                cell = Cell3

            }


        return cell

    }
```

As you can see each tab has different custom cells with images.

Below are the problems I am facing

1) it takes time to reload data when I switch tabs and their is considerable lag time. On iphone 4s it is worse

2) When I open this page, first tab is selected by default, so when i scroll, everything works smoothly. But when i switch tabs, and when i scroll again after reloading of data, the scroll becomes jerky and immediately i get memory warning issue.

What I did so far?

1) I commented the image fetching code and checked whether that is causing jerky scroll, but its not.

2) I used time profiler, to check what is taking more time, and it points the "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier". So I dont know what is going wrong here.

Comment: You code looks jumbled. You dequeue a cell of type kCellIdentifier before you check which tab is active. You also say you're loading images each time. Are you loading those images from the network in order to fill your cells? If so, you need a method to cache the contents locally so that if you scroll away and then scroll back, the image is saved locally. You also need to make sure your image loading is asynchronous. You may want to install a placeholder image into the cell while you're waiting for the image to load.

Comment: @DuncanC, When I open this page, by default it will be tab1, so I will dequeue cell of type "kCellIdentifier". As you can see in my code, I am asynchronously loading images.

Comment: @DuncanC, you can see in my code, I already have a imageCache

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not look "symmetric" with respect to cell set up when `secodTabClicked` and `thirdTabClicked`. I do not see `firstTabClicked`, and it looks to me that the condition that you are using to determine which tab is clicked overlaps with `secodTabClicked` and `thirdTabClicked`. In other words, you are probably getting into the top branch, and return `EventTableViewCell` when `cell2TableViewCell` or `cell3TableViewCell` are expected.

Refactoring your code to make type selection "symmetric" with respect to all three cell types should fix this problem.

Another solution could be making separate data sources for different tabs, and switching the data source instead of setting `xyzTabClicked` flags. You would end up with thee small functions in place of one big function, which should make your code easier to manage.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I am already using three different identifiers, sorry i didnt mention in the code. I have updated my code

Comment: @Ranjit It must be something else then - I replaced the answer wit a direction that could probably lead to a solution. I would explore the different data source option, too, because three small functions are better than one large function.

Comment: Hey, when I open this page, I call a webservice, which gives me three different types of data, which I store in three different arrays. Now when user switches tabs, I just load data from different arrays. Actually everything works, but its very slow and also i receive memory warning

Comment: Also I have 3 bool variables to check which tab is clicked.